# Selenium xpath unable to locate class

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am working on a project to scrape data. I have a for loop that runs through 50 urls (all of which are the same page with just different information) and then I extract different things to add to a csv. The problem I am having is that when I try to extract 'job_title' in my code, many of the entries come up as 'None', though the entry is actually existent. The HTML seems to be same in each URL, but 10/50 urls are yielding 'NONE' to the following lines of code. I need the code to set job_title = 'Founder'

This is the code I am currently using:

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source) 
job_title = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').extract_first()
```

Here is the HTML from one of the urls that I was unable to extract job_title--Which is 'Founder' in this case. It is the second line of the script.

```html
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section mb2">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Founder</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Company Name</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
    Genamint
    <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Full-time</span>
  </p>
  <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>Mar 2020 – Present</span>
    </h4>
    <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
      <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">5 mos</span>
    </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
    <span>New York, United States</span>
  </h4>

  <!---->
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look for namespace problem ? What's the result if you input this XPath : `//*[local-name()='h3'][contains(@class,"t-16 t-black t-bold")]`. Whitespace problem ? Could you test the following expression : `//h3[contains(@class,"t-16") and contains(@class,"t-black") and contains(@class,"t-bold")]` ?

Comment: Both those lines grab this HTML.                                                                                           '<h3 class="nav-settings__member-name t-16 t-black t-bold"> Ethan Roberti </h3>'

Answer (score 0):

> Both those lines grab this HTML. `<h3 class="nav-settings__member-name t-16 t-black t-bold> Ethan Roberti </h3>`

There's no `nav-settings__member-name` in your sample data. Since you're using `extract_first()`, you get the first appearing result. One way to fix it would be :

```
(//div[contains(@class,"pv-entity__summary")])[1]//h3/text()
```

Output : `Founder`

Assuming you're trying to scrape LinkedIn, to get the current or last job of a person, use the following XPath :

```
(//section[@class="experience pp-section" or @id="experience-section"]//h3)[1]/text()
```

For example, for https://www.linkedin.com/in/ethan-roberti-322694174, you'll get :

Output : `Summer Analyst`